# How to change the frontend payment method label in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have added a new custom payment method. If you notice in the picture below, there was no label in it.

I couldn't understand where the label of these payment method derived from. I have tried to change all the matching label of other payment,Changing all of these variables have no effect on the frontend label...

```
`grep -r "\SPurchase Order\S" .

./app/locale/en_US/Mage_Payment.csv:"Purchase Order","Purchase Order"
./app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/config.xml: <title>Purchase Order</title>
./app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/system.xml: <label>Purchase Order</label>
```

[image: Payment Method Label]

How do set my missing payment label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the payment method label on frontend, in the admin panel go to System->Configuration->Sales->Payment Methods->Select the payment method whose label you want to change, then in the `Title` field, change the label.

For the case of a new payment method, we need to have a fields define in the `config.xml`

```
<fields>
    <!-- Other Fields -->
    <title>
         <label>Title</label>
         <label>Title</label>                                
         <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>                 
         <sort_order>10</sort_order>                         
         <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>                
         <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>                
         <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
    </title>
    <!-- Other Fields -->
</fields>
```

Lastly change the value from the admin panel.

Comment: Great, :) I also just found out that the admin overwrite the default value for "Cash on Delivery" and "Purchase Order" Thanks. I'm now going to try to add my own title on to the admin, and see if that's work for the empty label

Comment: Yup, solved. I'll make some edit to your answer. So that we could add a new label to the payment information.